# addEventListener is not being applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a form in React JS and I am  using Firebase Firestore as a database. I wanted to save data to the database on clicking the submit button. So, I added a event listener, which listens for the submit button. But for some reason the event listener isn't being applied.

**The part which isn't working**

```
    $(window).on('load', function () {

        const form = document.querySelector('#donatorDetails');

        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            db.collection('donators').add({
                name: form.name.value,
                district: form.district.value,
                phoneNumber: form.phoneNumber.value,
                bloodGroup: form.bloodGroup.value,
                vaccineDays: form.vaccineDays.value
            });
            form.name.value = '';
            form.district.value = '';
            form.phoneNumber.value = '';
            form.bloodGroup.value = '';
            form.vaccineDays.value = '';
        });

    });
```

**Entire JS**

```
import React from 'react'
import './Form.css'
import { db } from './firebase'
import $ from 'jquery';


function Form() {


    // saving data for some reason


    $(window).on('load', function () {

        const form = document.querySelector('#donatorDetails');

        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            db.collection('donators').add({
                name: form.name.value,
                district: form.district.value,
                phoneNumber: form.phoneNumber.value,
                bloodGroup: form.bloodGroup.value,
                vaccineDays: form.vaccineDays.value
            });
            form.name.value = '';
            form.district.value = '';
            form.phoneNumber.value = '';
            form.bloodGroup.value = '';
            form.vaccineDays.value = '';
        });

    });



    return (
        <div className="Form" onLoad="{">
            <div>
                <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
                <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title>Document</title>
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                <div>
                    <div id="form-style">
                        <form id="donatorDetails" onKeyPress={e => {
                            if (e.key === 'Enter') e.preventDefault();
                        }} >
                            <label htmlFor="name" id="name-label">Your Full Name:</label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" required />
                            <br></br>

                            <label htmlFor="district" id="district-div">Choose Your District:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="district" list="districtname" id="district-div" required />
                            <datalist id="districtname">
                                <option value="Entire Karnataka"></option>
                                <option value="Bagalkot">
                                </option><option value="Ballari (Bellary)">
                                </option><option value="Belagavi (Belgaum)">
                                </option><option value="Bengaluru (Bangalore) Rural">
                                </option><option value="Bengaluru (Bangalore) Urban">
                                </option><option value="Bidar">
                                </option><option value="Chamarajanagar">
                                </option><option value="Chikballapur">
                                </option><option value="Chikkamagaluru (Chikmagalur)">
                                </option><option value="Chitradurga">
                                </option><option value="Dakshina Kannada">
                                </option><option value="Davangere">
                                </option><option value="Dharwad">
                                </option><option value="Gadag">
                                </option><option value="Hassan">
                                </option><option value="Haveri">
                                </option><option value="Kalaburagi (Gulbarga)">
                                </option><option value="Kodagu">
                                </option><option value="Kolar">
                                </option><option value="Koppal">
                                </option><option value="Mandya">
                                </option><option value="Mysuru (Mysore)">
                                </option><option value="Raichur">
                                </option><option value="Ramanagara">
                                </option><option value="Shivamogga (Shimoga)">
                                </option><option value="Tumakuru (Tumkur)">
                                </option><option value="Udupi">
                                </option><option value="Uttara Kannada (Karwar)">
                                </option><option value="Vijayapura (Bijapur)">
                                </option><option value="Yadgir">
                                </option></datalist>

                            <br></br>
                            <label htmlFor="phone-number">Phone Number:</label>
                            <input type="number" id="phone-number" name="phoneNumber" min={1000000000} max={9999999999} required />

                            <br></br>
                            <label htmlFor="bloodGroup">Your Blood Group:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bloodGroup" id="bloodGroup" list="bloodGroupList" />
                            <datalist id="bloodGroupList">
                                <option value="A+"></option>
                                <option value="A-"></option>
                                <option value="B+"></option>
                                <option value="B-"></option>
                                <option value="AB+"></option>
                                <option value="AB-"></option>
                            </datalist>

                            <br></br>
                            <label htmlFor="vaccine-days">Number of days since you were vaccinated or infected:</label>
                            <input type="number" name="vaccineDays" id="vaccineDays" />

                            <br></br>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit-button" />

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}


export default Form
```

Comment: Your not meant to use `addEventListener` with React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the form is rendered you add an event listener so that when the `load` event fires on the window, stuff happens.

This:

- Stacks up lots of duplicate event handlers
- Never fires because the load event happened before the Form was rendered for the first time

---

In general, **never bind event handlers directly to the DOM when using React**.

(There are some exceptions, but those are tricky edge cases that usually involve content generated by third party libraries).

If you want a submit event handler, then put it in the form's `onSubmit` prop.

```
<form id="donatorDetails" onSubmit={ submitHandlerFunction } ...
```

---

Further reading:

- [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) (React documentation)
- [Handling form submission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_interactivity_events_state#handling_form_submission) (MDN React interactivity: Events and state)

Comment: So I wrap the code in a function. And trigger it when it is submitted. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add an event listener. You can directly define a function inside your component and pass it to your form's onSubmit attribute.

```js
function Form() {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection("donators").add({
      name: form.name.value,
      district: form.district.value,
      phoneNumber: form.phoneNumber.value,
      bloodGroup: form.bloodGroup.value,
      vaccineDays: form.vaccineDays.value,
    });
    form.name.value = "";
    form.district.value = "";
    form.phoneNumber.value = "";
    form.bloodGroup.value = "";
    form.vaccineDays.value = "";
  };

  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* form body */}</form>;
}

export default Form;
```